# how to send nested json as request param in swift?

Tags: json, swift, swift2

My backend expects the following json for login.

```
{
"userName": "username",
"password" : "password",
"deviceInfoObj": {
"uniqueId":"q33qq3wr3wrw",
"model" : "6S"
}
}
```

Here is what I have

```
let deviceInfoObj: [String : String] = [
                    "uniqueId": "4d600df2c7e7c55",
                    "model": "6S"
            ]

let loginParams: [String:String] = [
                "userName": String(uname) ,
                "password" : String(pwd),
                "deviceInfo": deviceInfoObj
```

Here is how I make the request.

`engine.sendRequestWithParms(loginParams, serviceUrl: NSURL(string: urlString))`.

I get build error:

`cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-string-to-expected-argument-type-string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
let loginParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
  "userName": String(uname) ,
  "password" : String(pwd),
  "deviceInfo": deviceInfoObj
]
```

Comment: should that be "let deviceInfoObj" or "let loginParams"?

Comment: Edited, sorry for typo

Comment: Thread 42: "Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)"